# Bar chart in Vaadin Charts doesn't seem to respect the dateformat if all the data in the DataSeries is for the same month?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-charts

[image]If my DataSeries is spread over multiple months then everything works as expected, however if all the data is within a single month it displays a weird x axis label. My code is:

```
configuration.getxAxis().setType(AxisType.DATETIME);
configuration.getxAxis().setDateTimeLabelFormats(new DateTimeLabelFormats("%b %Y", "%Y"));
```

I've attached a screenshot to show what I mean. For that chart I have 3 items in the DataSeries, all for the month of Jan 2018. The format I'd like is Jan 2018 on the x-axis